# Mac Excel >1 variable in IF statement (but NOT nested IF statements)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

=IF(Values_Entered,Loan_Amount,"") is the formula
Value_Entered = =IF('Loan Amortization Schedule'!$D$12<>"",1,0)

?? Two variables in the IF (with no AND or OR or NESTED IF)
?? Don't know how the ,1,0 work at end of the first Values_Entered (hidden formula)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is the correct understanding of your question, correct me if it is not.

In IF formula: 
1st parameter is the condition, 2nd parameter is the statement when condition is `True`, 3rd parameter is the statement when condition is `False`

> Don't know how the ,1,0 work at end of the first Values_Entered (hidden formula)

The 1,0 in the end of `Values_entered` works like a flag. In this case, Excel recognize `1` as `True` while `0` as `False`.

With this being said, the first formula, in human readable way, is:

```
If Values_Entered is True or 1, show Loan_Amount. Otherwise, show nothing.
```

Comment: So value_entered (has a formula behind it the If(loan amort...).  So if I understand correctly, you're saying in 'readable' form, if there is a value_entered then the '1' means if value entered true so there are '2' checks, one in the value_entered hidden formula and also the '1'.  So if value_entered is true the show the loan_amount, otherwise show nothing?

Comment: I slightly change my wording in the code block. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

=IF(**Values_Entered**,Loan_Amount,"")

Value_Entered is:  =IF('Loan Amortization Schedule'!$D$12<>"",1,0)

I think the first formula is missing a condition (in bold)

The value in Value_Entered is checked from the cell D12 in the worksheet named: Loan Amortization Schedule.

If D12 not empty, it will be 1 (True)
If D12 is empty, it will be 0 (False)

So in the first formula, the value from D12 is compared with another cell which is Loan_Amount.

Would you be able to tell me what you want to see in the actual cell? Or is this an existing formula in the sheet you are trying to understand.

Currently, what will happen  is as long as there is a value in Loan_Amount, it is copied in the cell where your first formula is.